# What happened when I exceeded the range of the charge amplifier?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I have a charge amplifier built with the assistance of [this datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa033a/sloa033a.pdf).

According to this datasheet,

[image]

In this charge amplifier I built, (see below) the input is 50mA and Cf is 100u. As

[image]

This results in an output voltage of 50V, which exceeds the rated voltage.

[image]

As a result, the system does not provide the mathematically expected input.

**What I want to know, however, is why the system failed the way it did.** My output looks like this.

[image]

If the voltage is exceeded, I would have expected it to reach a constant 14-15V (compensating for
usual op-amp tolerances), but not fluctuate wildly between 1 and 13V. Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Are you referring to a real piece of hardware that got "bricked," or are you using "bricked" to mean that your simulation does strange things?

Comment: The latter. I've clarified the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What I want to know, however, is why the system bricked the way it did*

The above became this after the question  was edited: -

> *What I want to know, however, is why the system failed the way it did*

and

> *In this charge amplifier I built, (see below) the input is 50mA*

When you input 50 mA into a circuit of this type, the op-amp has to do something with that 50 mA in order to maintain the virtual ground at the inverting terminal. In other words the op-amp output has to be able to sink or source 50 mA.

Given that the TL071 op-amp can only muster an output current of 26 mA into a short circuit, there's no-way that this will work.

Answer (score 1):

After a close look, your circuit appears to be operating correctly.

- Your current source is providing pulses at the rate of 10 per second.  The output of the op-amp is pulsing at the rate of 10 pulses per second.  That looks reasonable to me.  The output follows the input, just as it should.
- The pulses at the output reach about 13V at the peaks, about what I'd expect from a [TL071 operating on 15V.](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tl071.pdf)  On a 15V power supply, the TL071 output can reach about 13.5V.  The output voltage swing of the TL071 is given in the datasheet.

In all, the circuit and the simulation seem to be OK. The output follows the input pulses, and amplifies them.  Its output clips to a level appropriate to the IC and the supply voltage.